# How can I change folder or file permissions when mount in Azure storage service?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, gitlab

Please..Waiting for your earnest answers.

My development environment is `Azure cloud - Kubernetes`
and I want to install the Gitlab Docker image in Azure's storage service.

Look at the log below, Gitlab starts up and tries to change the permissions of Azure storage, but Azure storage does not allow this.

Eventually, Gitlab cannot be started.

I tried changing the mount option when loading Kubernetes' StorageClass, pv, and pvc, but couldn't apply it.

Please answer for this..

```sh
================================================================================
    Error executing action `create` on resource 'storage_directory[/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh]'
    ================================================================================
    Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
    ------------------------------------
    ruby_block[directory resource: /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/resources/storage_directory.rb line 34) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
    ---- Begin output of chmod 00700 /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh ----
    STDOUT:
    STDERR: chmod: changing permissions of '/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh': Operation not permitted
    ---- End output of chmod 00700 /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh ----
    Ran chmod 00700 /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh returned 1
    Cookbook Trace:
    ---------------
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/libraries/storage_directory_helper.rb:35:in `run_command'
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/libraries/storage_directory_helper.rb:55:in `ensure_permissions_set'
    /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/resources/storage_directory.rb:40:in `block (3 levels) in class_from_file'
    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/gitlab-shell.rb
     34:   storage_directory dir do
     35:     owner git_user
     36:     group git_group
     37:     mode "0700"
     38:   end
     39: end
    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/gitlab-shell.rb:34:in `block in from_file'
    storage_directory("/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh") do
      action [:create]
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      declared_type :storage_directory
      cookbook_name "gitlab"
      recipe_name "gitlab-shell"
      owner "git"
      group "git"
      mode "0700"
      path "/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh"
    end
    System Info:
    ------------
    chef_version=14.14.29
    platform=ubuntu
    platform_version=16.04
    ruby=ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux]
    program_name=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client
    executable=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client
Running handlers:
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:
storage_directory[/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh] (gitlab::gitlab-shell line 34) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: ruby_block[directory resource: /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/resources/storage_directory.rb line 34) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of chmod 00700 /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: chmod: changing permissions of '/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh': Operation not permitted
---- End output of chmod 00700 /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh ----
Ran chmod 00700 /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh returned 1
Running handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 7 resources updated in 07 seconds
```